# Parse two HTML String with JS - and convert one to Int

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm currently parsing the first string already and everything works fine:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var element;

function search() { 
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        element = links[i];
        var price = parseInt(element);
        if (element.href.indexOf("http://www.myurl.com") == 0)  {
           //program goes here
        }
    }
 }
```

However, each of the hyperlinks (products) has another string with the price on it (in the same div element). This would look like this:

```
 <span class="price_table_value">
            Pricetag:<br>
            <span style="color:white">239,--€ </span>
 </span>
```

I would love to somehow parse that too and use parseInt() to make an Integer out of it.

I've thinking about this for a hour and cant find a good solution (im still beginning to learn JS). Any help/ideas?

Comment: how exactly is the `a` related to that `span` tag? (`span` is wrapped in `a`?)

Comment: for numbers with decimal point, like prices, it's better to use `parseFloat` to preserve that decimal (unless you don't want to of course)

Comment: I basically just want to check for the correct links first, which I do in the given code and then, if an item of interest is found, I want to be able to compare its price to my max value and run through another if: `if (parseInt(right_code_goes_here) <= 199) {
//perform actions
}`

That's basically what I would be looking for.

Comment: @KingKing the first JavaScript example isn't related to the HTML block.  The JavaScript block he provided is an example of something else he got working.  Now he wants to write up a script for the second HTML block to parse the int in the inner span.

Comment: @Xero the confusing thing to me is this ***each of the hyperlinks (products) has another string with the price on it***. So I wonder about the relationship here (the concrete HTML structure, because that's important).

Comment: Post one of your `a` links and show how it's related to that span tag.

Comment: @kingKing, Oh, yeah.  Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go with something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjxr3twj/1/)?

Basically, this should go in you loop body, but replace the `[0]` with `i`, and add the logic you need:

```
var rawPrice = $(element).children('.price_table_value').children('span').text();
var price = parseFloat(rawPrice);
```

Of course only do it if you're 100% certain the price format will start with the price value (`parseFloat` will trim anything trailing the number, just as King Kong noticed). Also, you may want to wrap it around a try/catch block (and best always do it when parsing).

Please note that generally, you probably should be getting such values from some sort of API, not just getting these from DOM elements like this, so please make sure that's what you want to do.

Comment: if the string starts with a number, then `parseFloat` will automatically trims end the non-numeric string and returns the correct number, so no need to use split. See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/L9r89bjw/

Comment: Thanks, you're right of course, I overlooked that. Updated the answer.

Comment: Okay, basically I know how to use the element now, my only problem is that the string doesn't start with a number... so `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` will return NaN.

Any workarounds/ideas?

Comment: What does it start with then? If you're getting as deep as in the span inside the span with class price_table_value , there is only the "239,--€" string to parse.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought I replied to Vijay. Your solution is perfect and works just well.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Great, happy to hear. Wouldn't mind if you accepted my answer then ;)

Comment: I just found an issue with this :/

There are many items on the page im planning to use this and right now the returned is always the price of the first item (all items have spans with the name "price_table_value".

Is there any way I can just "browse" the element that I just found in my first parsing and comparing operation (see my code) by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for the continous help. Unfortunately gives back "NaN" :(

Comment: Could you paste here what you exactly get in `links[i].html()`?

Comment: For `             console.log(element);
        console.log(price);` this is my result: `<a class="market_listing_row_link" href="http://url.com" id="resultlink_1"> <div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult" id="result_1">...</div></a>
NaN`

Comment: Okay, I think we're abusing the comment system ;) please let me know your email so we can exchange info

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one...

```
function search() { 
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    element = links[i];
    var price =parseInt($(".price_table_value").value);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just other example without jQuery:

```
var priceHolder = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".price_table_value span"));
priceHolder.forEach(function(item) {
    var price = /([0-9]+[.0-9]?)/.test(item.innerHTML) ? parseFloat(RegExp.$1) : 0;
    console.log(price);
});
```

Here is working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zono/9gL1vw0e/9/

Comment: The asnwer is edited. Will handle floating point numbers also.